# I have just installed Linux 22.04 and cannot play videos

Tags: vlc, dvd

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 and typed the following in the command terminal:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras && sudo apt install vlc
```

I accepted the t&cs and it seemed to install OK (no error messages). Unfortunately I cannot play DVDs with either "videos" or vlc. With vlc, I get the following error message on the video screen when trying to play the film Bohemian Rhapsody:

Your input can't be opened:

```
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///media/chris/BOHEMIAN_RHAPSODY/VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB'. Check the log for details.
```

Comment: So "Check the log for details"

Comment: OK, any idea how I would do this? I'm not very knowledgeable on ubuntu as you have no doubt already gathered

Comment: @C.Diamantis vlc logs ('messages' now!) on the newer vlc are accessed with Control + M. Then adjust the verbosity levels (bottom left). Or from the command line: `cvlc -v <input_file>`.

Answer (score 3):

Have you installes libdvd-pkg

```
sudo apt install libdvd-pkg
```

And then

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg
```

Comment: Now installed but made no difference. Still getting same error message

Comment: @C.Diamantis And just to be sure: libdvdread8 is also installed?

Comment: Yes, libdvdread8 is already the newest version (according to command terminal message)

Comment: An update on what I've tried:
1) removed, reinstalled vlc and ubuntu-restricted-extras about 10 times
2) Performed a search with aptitude for both vlc files and libdvd files (I couldn't see anything untoward in the list or obvious omissions but don't really know what I'm looking for)
3) set up a log file in vlc, tried to play the DVD once more and then reviewed the log file (this consisted of 124 lines, none of which with my limited knowledge could I say was the definitive problem or not)
4) Sat back exhausted because I've spent 2 days of my time and have got nowhere

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 systems that I upgraded from ubuntu server 20.04/10 to 22.04 and 1 system with a clean install of ubuntu server 22.04 that all had the same problem. It manifested itself by not running my bash scripts containing vlc commands to grab rtsp:// streams from several security camera's scheduled by crontab. Unfortunately, none of these suggestions worked, as neither did multiple other fixes found by searching for hours.

I remembered seeing a reference in one post https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=158071&p=520527 about the ubuntu vlc debs package not supporting rtsp:// but the snap package did. I fully removed and purged the debs vlc:

sudo apt remove --purge vlc libdvd-pkg libdvdcss2 {any other packages installed to support vlc}

and installed snap vlc:

sudo snap install vlc

with joyful success.

For me this was a case of support specifically for rtsp:// but maybe it will work for other problems too. I've used ubuntu debs vlc for years. Why are they now not supporting rtsp:// streams? Huh! Pushing the snap package I suppose.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: stupid ai bots with useless comments

Answer (score 0):

Ensure libdvdcss2 is installed as well as previous recommendations.

Comment: Addressed in subsequent question posted yesterday "cannot play DVDs after installing Linux 22.04"

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by getting VLC from repository ppa:videolan/master-daily instead of default one:

1. sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
2. sudo apt-get update
3. sudo apt install vlc

There may be a better way fixing the bug that occurred with upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04, but at least it worked, while re-installation and dpkg-reconfigure didn't...