# VLC is not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, vlc, video-player

I just upgraded my system from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, however, the VLC media player is not working at all, I tried to uninstall it and re-install it (vlc 3.0.18) again using `sudo snap install vlc` but it's still not launching

I tried the solutions from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1405178/i-have-just-installed-linux-22-04-and-cannot-play-videos) thread, but nothing worked. One solution suggested to install from `ppa:videolan/master-daily` and then `sudo apt-get install vlc` and it did work, however, the app was [unstable](https://launchpad.net/%7Evideolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily#:%7E:text=You%20can%20update%20your%20system%20with%20unsupported%20packages%20from%20this%20untrusted%20PPA%20by%20adding%20ppa%3Avideolan/master%2Ddaily%20to%20your%20system%27s%20Software%20Sources.%20(Read%20about%20installing)).
I checked their [bug tracking](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues) system, no one reported such an issue over there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Have you tried installing VLC from the default repository by just using the following command:

   ```
   sudo apt install vlc
   ```
2. You can also try installing VLC using flatpak:

   ```
   sudo apt install flatpak
   sudo flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
   flatpak install flathub org.videolan.VLC
   ```

You can refer to following guide.

https://linuxgenie.net/how-to-install-vlc-in-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: the flatpak actually worked. thanks.

Comment: when I installed it from sudo apt install vlc, the app wasn't stable, it had weird behaviors

Comment: @AhmadBader if flatpak worked, please mark the answer as resolved.

Comment: about 500mb for flatpak version but at last chromecast is working  

Answer (score 5):

**Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS**

```
sudo rm /var/cache/fontconfig/*
rm ~/.cache/fontconfig/*
fc-cache -r
```

[See the original post](https://askubuntu.com/a/1454415/776753)

Answer (score 1):

Faced the same issue.

VLC 3.0.18 installed from Snap is missing this package:

```
sudo apt install libaribb24-0
```

Answer (score 0):

Open "Applications", uninstall the snap-VLC, reinstall VLC from "ubuntu-jammy-universe (deb)"
There is a drop-down in the upper right corner which says "snap-store (Snap)" by default

Edit: Check if you have corrupted packages (after upgrade). Me, I had a "broken" libdvd... So you may try to fix this first:
`sudo dpkg-reconfigure libdvd-pkg`

Answer (score 0):

Good reference for [How to Fix Video Stuck or Freeze in VLC](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/fix-video-stuck-or-freezing-in-vlc/)
I had similar problems with VLC on my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and the methods outlined in this 'How to' article worked for me.

- Method 1: Update VLC Media Player to the latest version
- Method 2: Increase cache values in VLC Player
- Method 3: Disable Hardware Decoding in VLC Player
- Method 4: Change FFmpeg settings in VLC Player
- Method 5: Switch video output to DirectX DirectDraw in VLC